# How to use fgetpwent()

Tags: c, rpc

I have to develop a rpc program that shows all users conected to the server, showing whose ones are system users and whose are normal users.
I have looked up in many post but I still don't know how to use fgetpwent() propertly, with the code I leave bellow.

There may be more errors that I have not found yet, but my question is about the use of fgetpwent()

Server Code:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include "entrega3.h"

salidaop1 *
op1_1_svc(void *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{

        struct passwd {
                char    *pw_name;       /* nombre de usuario */
                char    *pw_passwd;     /* contraseña cifrada */
                uid_t   pw_uid;         /* id. del usuario */
                gid_t   pw_gid;         /* id. del grupo primario */
                char    *pw_gecos;      /* nombre real */
                char    *pw_dir;        /* directorio de inicio */
                char    *pw_shell;      /* programa caparazón */
        };

        static salidaop1 result ;
        FILE *file ;
        int numSystemUsers, numNormalUsers, index1, index2 ;
        struct passwd *users ;

        xdr_free((xdrproc_t) xdr_salidaop1, (char *) &result) ;

        file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r") ;

        while(users = fgetpwent(file)) {
          if (users -> pw_uid >= 1000) numNormalUsers++ ;
          else numSystemUsers++ ;
        }

        fclose(file) ;

        result.system.v1_len = numSystemUsers ;
        result.normal.v2_len = numNormalUsers ;
        result.system.v1_val = malloc(result.system.v1_len * sizeof(char)) ;
        result.normal.v2_val = malloc(result.normal.v2_len * sizeof(char)) ;

        file = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r") ;

        index1 = 0;
        index2 = 0;
        while(users = fgetpwent(file)) {
          if (users -> pw_uid >= 1000) {
            result.normal.v2_val[index2] = *users -> pw_name ;
            index2++;
          } else {
            result.system.v1_val[index1] = *users -> pw_name ;
            index1++;
          }
        }

        fclose(file) ;

        return &result;
}
```

Client Code:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "entrega3.h"


void
nprog_1(char *host, int opcion)
{
        CLIENT *clnt;
        salidaop1  *result_1;
        char *op1_1_arg;

#ifndef DEBUG
        clnt = clnt_create (host, NPROG, NVERS, "udp");
        if (clnt == NULL) {
                clnt_pcreateerror (host);
                exit (1);
        }
#endif  /* DEBUG */
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                result_1 = op1_1((void*)&op1_1_arg, clnt);
                if (result_1 == (salidaop1 *) NULL) {
                        clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
                } else {
                  printf("Los usuarios del sistema son: ");
                  for (int i = 0; i < result_1 -> system.v1_len ; i++)
                    printf("%d, ", result_1 -> system.v1_val[i]) ;
                  printf("\nLos usuarios normales son: ");
                  for (int i = 0; i < result_1 -> normal.v2_len ; i++)
                    printf("%d, ", result_1 -> normal.v2_val[i]) ;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
#ifndef DEBUG
        clnt_destroy (clnt);
#endif   /* DEBUG */
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *host;
        int opcion;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf ("usage: %s server_host\n", argv[0]);
                exit (1);
        }
        host = argv[1];

        setbuf(stdin, NULL) ;
        printf("\n+------------------------+\n");
        printf("|       Bienvenido       |\n");
        printf("+------------------------+\n");
        printf("| 1. Usuarios Conectados |\n");
        printf("| 2. Usuarios Conectados |\n");
        printf("| 3. Salir               |\n");
        printf("+------------------------+\n");

        printf("\nSeleccione una opción (1 - 3): ") ;
        scanf("%d", &opcion) ;

        if (opcion == 3) exit(0);
        if (opcion < 1 || opcion > 3) {
            printf("Error al selecionar la opción.\n") ;
            exit(1);
        }

        nprog_1 (host, opcion);
exit (0);
}
```

When I run both, server and client I get an infinity loop:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xXZB.png)

I don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: Your use of the `fgetpwent` function is okay and fine. There are other problems though, like you forgetting (or perhaps not knowing) that uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized, with an indeterminate value.

Comment: The "infinite loop" comes not from `fgetpwent` but from somewhere else. Use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement to see what happens.

Comment: `result.system.v1_val = malloc(result.system.v1_len * sizeof(char*)) ;` [and: you need strdup()]

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to your comments I have checked the memory reserve with `malloc` and it already works, thanks for your help